# Trouble with type casting in c#

Tags: c#, casting

I have 2 classes:

```
class A {
    public void A_1(Object b) {
        ...
        Type t = b.GetType();
        (t.FullName)b.B_1(); //It doesn`t work! Error in cast
    }
    ....
}

class B {
    public void B_1() {
        ...
    }
    ....
}

A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.A1(b);
```

How to cast object correctly?

Comment: Uhhh, why must you pass in an `Object` of `b` if you're always going to call a `B` instance method? Why not just pass it as a `B` directly? No need for a cast then.

Comment: Or if the argument is not always of type 'B', use an interface, or generics.

Comment: Because, I don't know exactly type of object in method A_1(Object b)

Comment: @mystdeim - If you don't know the type, then how do you know it can be cast to B?  Do you know for sure that the type inherits from B?

Comment: Try to specify common interface with method B_1() for all the types, that can be passed in method A_1(). Another tip: you can check if one type can be casted (inherits, to be more precise) to another using operator is. if (A is B) { ... }

Comment: If all of the answers and advices haven't help you (ONLY IF IT IS) and no any another way to do what you want and you are using .net 4.0, you can use dynamic type. But the situation seems like it can be solved by more 'humanity' way :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to cast an object of any type to an object of another type, you do this:

```
// Will Throw an exception at runtime if it cant be cast.
B newObject = (B)oldObject; 

// Will return null at runtime if the object cannot be cast
B newObject = oldObject as B; 

// If in a generic method, convert based on the generic type parameter regardless of condition - will throw an exception at runtime if it cant be cast
B newObject = (T)Convert.ChangeType(oldObject, typeof(T))
```

Your syntax is off; you don't convert from the fullname to the object, you simply convert from the type symbol.

```
double x = (double)40;

ClassB anotherInstance = (ClassB)someOtherInstance;
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is basically:

```
Foo myFoo = ("Foo")myObject;
```

That definitely will not work in C#. When you cast in C#, the compiler emits code that does the cast, it needs to know what it's casting from and to, in order to write that code. A string does not help the compiler out here.

As others have pointed out, what you want to do doesn't seem like you really need to (unless this is just a contrived example). If you really want to do this, you'll need to work with a more dynamic language than C#, or find a C# friendly way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you didn't mean to do `(B)b.B_1()`?

Comment: Should be `((B) b).B_1();` I think? Otherwise the method call would happen first, then the cast. But before that, everything blows into smithereens because you can't cast a void return and you couldn't execute that method on an `Object` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

C# has a static type-system, i.e. all types must be known at compile-time (modulo reflection). So, casting to a type that is only known at run-time makes no sense. Specify the type explicitly:

```
public void A_1(object obj)
{
    ...
    B b = (B)obj;
    b.B_1();
    // or
    ((B)obj).B_1();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
class A {
    public void A_1(Object b) {
        ...
        if (b is B)
        {
             ((B)b).B_1();
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Type.FullName` is just a string; it's not a type.  Use this instead: `((B)b).B_1();`  Also, using `GetType()` is a way to get the type of an object dynamically, but casting is only possible or useful when the target type is known at compile time (not dynamic at all).  In order to cast, simply refer to the type directly in a pair of parentheses.  Don't attempt to obtain or use an object of type `Type`.